# VBA Function query using IF formula

Tags: vba, function, if-statement, formula

I'm trying to create a VBA function which generates quite a complex formula if there's a particular value in Cell G25. Can anyone help please?

My formula is: 
=IF(G25="46mm",INDEX(Matrix!A:K,AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25)/(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25))*ROW(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13),1),AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$C$5:$G$5>=I25)/(Matrix!$C$5:$G$5>=I25))*COLUMN(Matrix!$C$5:$G$5),1)),IF(G25="67mm",INDEX(Matrix!A:K,AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25)/(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25))*ROW(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13),1),AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$C$5:$K$5>=I25)/(Matrix!$C$5:$K$5>=I25))*COLUMN(Matrix!$C$5:$K$5),1)),IF(G25="90mm",INDEX(Matrix!A:K,AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25)/(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13>=M25))*ROW(Matrix!$B$6:$B$13),1),AGGREGATE(15,3,((Matrix!$C$5:$G$5>=I25)/(Matrix!$C$5:$G$5>=I25))*COLUMN(Matrix!$C$5:$G$5),1)))))+AL25

I'm currently using the above formula in Cell AG25 but it's generating a #VALUE! error where there's no content in cell G25.

Ideally this function will apply to any cells in range g25:g56 dependant on the value in range a25:a56

Comment: Does it work when there is data in G25

Comment: Do 46mm and 90mm do the same thing?  I would recommend changing the `IF` part to where the it is actually needed, so in this case, it looks like you'd need, `....IF(OR(G25="46mm",G25="90mm"),(Matrix!$C$5:$G$5>=I25),(Matrix!$C$5:$K$5>=I25))...` within the AGGREGATE.

Comment: The formula works as a formula, but generates a #value! error of there's no data in the G25:g56 range.

Comment: It's basically a price matrix for something that is 46mm and 90mm, so it's looking up two different prices

Comment: For a matrix, you can use `INDEX(matrix,MATCH(yValue,column1,false),MATCH(xHeader,column1,false))` so if I wanted to know how much customer1 pays for a drill, I could say `INDEX(A1:X1000,MATCH("Customer1",a1:a100,false),MATCH("Drill",a1:x1,false))`  with customers being in column A and the header for products in row 1